# Operation of Junction field effect transistor

Tags: transistors, jfet

Is Vds necessay for Drain current (Id) or we can get Id by Vgs also as in books it is written that Vds is necessary.

Comment: If you open a door and there is nobody there to walk through it.. how many people walk through per second?

Comment: @trevor_G - A: All of them. LOL. (Sorry, but I could not resist)

Comment: unlike a bjt, no current flows from G to S, so it must come through D

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've already gotten the answer to this question from books, so I'm not sure why you're even asking. But to reiterate what you've read: the gate-source voltage creates a channel for current to pass through. The drain-source voltage creates current flow through the channel.